# Converting T-SQL to Linq

Tags: t-sql, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am using Entitry Framework 4.1 and I am struggling to understand how the convert the below query which uses joins and aggregate methods to a Linq to Entities call in the DomainService.

```
SELECT     tblTime.Period As Timeline, COUNT(tblEngineeringDashboard_ItemList.ID) AS Items
FROM         tblEngineeringDashboard_ItemList INNER JOIN
                      tblTime ON tblEngineeringDashboard_ItemList.TimeID = tblTime.ID
GROUP BY tblTime.Period
ORDER BY tblTime.Period
```

Can anyone provide help.

Possible Solution

```
Dim var = From i In ObjectContext.tblEngineeringDashboard_ItemList
                Join t In ObjectContext.tblTimes On i.TimeID Equals t.ID
                Group By i.TimeID Into Group
                Select DateStart = (From n In ObjectContext.tblTimes Where n.ID = TimeID Select n.Period), PartCount = Group.Count
```

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing which comes to mind is:

```
var q = from t in Context.Time
        group t by t.Period into g
        orderby g.Key
        select new 
        {
            Timeline = g.Key,
            Items = (from ti in g
                     from il in ti.ItemList // or whatever the property for the navigation to tblEngineeringDashboard_ItemList is called
                     select il).Count()
        };
```

However, the original SQL had an `INNER JOIN`, which would reject `tblTime` records without any matching records in `tblEngineeringDashboard_ItemList`. So you may want:

```
var q = from t in Context.Time
        where t.ItemList.Any()
        group t by t.Period into g
        orderby g.Key
        select new 
        {
            Timeline = g.Key,
            Items = (from ti in g
                     from il in ti.ItemList // or whatever the property for the navigation to tblEngineeringDashboard_ItemList is called
                     select il).Count()
        };
```

You can also flip the query around:

```
var q = from i in Context.EngineeringDashboardItemList
        where i.Time != null 
        group i by i.Time.Period into g
        orderby g.Key
        select new 
        {
            Timeline = g.Key,
            Items = g.Count()
        };
```

Comment: Hi Craig, I took your solution and after changing a few thing around got it to work but Im not sure I understand why or if my solution is the best.....         Dim var = From i In ObjectContext.tblEngineeringDashboard_ItemList
                        Join t In ObjectContext.tblTimes On i.TimeID Equals t.ID
                        Group By i.TimeID Into Group
                        Select DateStart = (From n In ObjectContext.tblTimes Where n.ID = TimeID Select n.Period), PartCount = Group.Count

Comment: [It is usually incorrect](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/) to use `Join()` in LINQ to Entities or LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Understood, but you need to be careful when using cross joins in case of creating Cartesian products. Its an undefied join across all possiblities. The LINQ is easier to read though.

Comment: There is no danger of accidentally creating a Cartesian product when using LINQ to Entities navigations. Indeed, one of their advantages is that it's impossible to screw up the `JOIN` conditions (the " `ON` ").

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
tblEngineeringDashboard_ItemList
    .Join(tblTime,ed => ed.TimeID ,t => t.ID, (ed,t) => new{ed,t})
.GoupBy(g => g.t.Period)
.Select(s => new 
          {
           Timeline = s.Key,
           Items = s.Count()
          }
       )
.OrderBy(o => o.Timeline)
```

Comment: Quite not. That count for instance would give the number of the tblTime rows grouped under a certain key, and not the number of total rows of the foreign key table under all the items that are grouped by the key. Check my answer.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but given that it is an inner join, should't it return the correct amount of rows?

Comment: In his sql query, he's counting the elements provided by the join. That translates in a selectmany in linq. If he was counting the rows returned by the query, then your approach would be right.

Answer (score 0):

While converting from sql to linq isn't an ideal approach (you should think directly in linq, translating your need to a linq query), the query you posted is rather simple.

```
var grouped = tblTime.OrderBy(c => c.Period).GroupBy(c => c.Period).Select(c =>
new {
       timeline = c.Key,
       count = c.SelectMany(x => x.tblEngineeringDashboard).Count()
    });
```

*Edit: There, fixed. Everything on the L2E engine.

This provided that there are correct foreign keys between the tables (thus you don't have to declare the join manually).

Comment: That gives you n+1 queries, presuming that lazy loading is turned on. If lazy loading is off, the `Count()` will be wrong.

Comment: Yes, I assumed that lazyloading is on, as I always work with it. I should have specified.

Comment: The n+1 is still a problem, though. You'll get the right answer... eventually.

Comment: I don't see that n+1 problem. I did this kind of query many times without any problem.

Comment: Try it in SQL profiler. You're lazily loading `c.tblEngineeringDashboard`. Worse, you're loading the individual records, not just the count. Enumerating `grouped` brings the results into object space; you've left L2E and `Count()` can no longer be pushed back to a SQL `COUNT`.

Comment: That's easily fixed removing the foreach loop and adding a .Select statement at the end of the query, so everything is in sql.

Comment: Yes, that's more or less the answer I gave. The performance is better by multiple orders of magnitude, even for a small result set.

Comment: Actually I always enumerate as late as possible, and only if I need an operation that isn't supported by L2E I enumerate sooner. My original answer was a simple "logic" approach, without any optimization in mind. Now it should be ok.